# Angular's $resources custom actions returns only $promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I present some small part of service. In random methods like `updateTinyUrl()`, `$resource` actions extract `$promise` and returns it for me, instead of returning object with `$promise`, `$resolved` additional properties, there i could extract `$promise` by myself. Regards to [documentations](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) all custom actions should return expanded object with  `$promise`, `$resolved`additional properties, but it's not always true. Ask you for help!

```
    var tinyUrl = $resource(null, {}, {
        'list':{ method: 'GET', url: '/api/tinyurl/list', isArray: false },
        'get':{ method: 'GET', url: '/api/tinyurl/get' },
        'update':{ method: 'POST', url: '/api/tinyurl/update' }
    });

    this.getTinyUrl = function (tinyUrlId) {
        return tinyUrl.get({tinyUrlId: tinyUrlId}).$promise;
    };

    this.updateTinyUrl = function (data) {
        return tinyUrl.update(data); // tinyUrl.update() returns promise instead of object with additional properties $promise and $resolved
    };
```

Comment: Are you sure POST /api/tinyurl/update is actually returning an object?  The api might just be saying, yep the object is updated, and leave it at that.